# How to display validation summary below the input controls?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following form:

```
<form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="RemoveDetails" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    @if (Model.RequirePassword)
    {
        <div id="password-container">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" />
                    <small>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="col-6">
        <hr class="mt-2 mb-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-style-1 btn-danger">Confirm</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If I leave the password empty, a validation message (the model uses `DataAnnonations`) is displayed right below the control. This is fine.

If I enter the wrong password, the `Post` action validates it and adds an error to the `ModelState`. This error is displayed below the form.

Is it possible to display such model errors below the relevant controls?

Comment: How do you think about it and is there any update sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in Controller: `ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "validation summary error.");` The error message won't display in `<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>`, but it can display error message in `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RemoveDetails" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="password-container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" />
                <small>
                    @*<span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>*@
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" id="description" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" />
                <small>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <hr class="mt-2 mb-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-style-1 btn-danger">Confirm</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>     
    </div>
</form>

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RemoveDetails(RemoveDetail rdl)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var pwd = rdl.Password;
        //do something here and find the password is wrong
        
        //code below won't display error message in <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger">
        //but can display error message in @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "validation summary error.");
        return View(rdl);

    }
    return View(rdl);
}
```

[image]